# Loading angular directive (customized table )from a td

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a directive to display the tables with input data. 
My requirement is on click from one table td, I want to load the details which are in tabular form( the directive is to load the table with data)
But I'm struggling here, this table is getting added in td, I want just after the clicked row td, one row should be inserted and within that table data should render from the directive.
So if anyone already struggled with this problem please share how you resolve it.

Below is the code snippet (html)

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-init="row.show=false" id="tableRow{{$index}}" role="row" class="odd" st-select-row="row" ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
    <td id="addTable" style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="displayReports($event,row)">
      <span ng-class="row.show? 'fa fa-caret-down iconSpan' : 'fa fa-caret-right iconSpan'"></span>
      <table-directive ng-if="row.show" data="row.reports"></table-directive>
    </td>
    <td>{{rowCollection.indexOf(row) + 1}}</td>
    <td class="sorting_1">{{row.name}}</td>
    <td class="sorting_1">{{row.reports.length}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlNDD.png)

[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRS4F.png)

In screen 1, I'm facing the issue

Comment: We don't know how your table-directive works, but try moving it from <td> to a new <tr> after the first row.

Comment: actly, based on row.show flag, i want table to be rendered, when I am trying with new <tr>, the row.show flag is always returning false as i have initialised with false.                on td ng-click= displayReport() - We are altering the row.show falg